# Type or namespace cannot be found, when reference does exist

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a wpf Application in which I am trying to reference a class library i have created.
I have added a reference to the .dll
And i have added the using statement to my file, and the intellisense actually sees the new namespace.

Then in my code I am able to create new objects of classes in my added .dll just fine. the intellisense sees all the methods ect..no problem, no errors.

when I try to build my wpf application, all the sudden I get the type or namespace cannot be found error on my added dll.

Then i get errors whenever i am trying to create objects from that .dll.

I don't get what is happening.. why does it work before I build, but when I build it decides it doesn't know where that .dll is i am referencing?

Also i have gone to that class library i am trying to add, and mades sure it builds with no errors.

Comment: make sure that the dll referencing isn't for higher level framework than your project. ie 3.5 project referencing 4.0 dll

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The most common cause of this is that your .DLL targets the full .NET Framework, but the WPF Application targets the Client Profile.

For example, if your library targets .NET 3.5, make sure your WPF Application targets the full .NET 3.5 or 4.0 framework, not the client profile.

Comment: Microsoft should give this link as a solution tip, instead of generic error message which does not make any sense.

Comment: Similarly, I've gotten this error when referencing a .NET 4.5 project from a .NET 4 project

Answer (score 5):

A few thoughts on this matter that you can try:

- Check that a lower version is not calling a higher version assembly (e.g. .NET 3.5 project is not calling a .NET 4.0 assembly).
- Clean -> Build (or Rebuild)
- Manually delete bin/obj folders of both caller and calling projects. This forces everything to be built - the 'hard ' way. This may sound redundant, but has worked for me a couple of times.
- Restart VS - sometimes, there is just no explanation.
- Reboot - when nothing else works, give it a break and try again.

Comment: Thanks, but this question is nearly three years old and resolved as I selected an answer which was the correct fix.

Comment: I'm just leaving this here in case it helps someone :)

Comment: @twaldron Item 1 on this checklist is what fixed the same problem for me. =)

Answer (score 0):

You can Copy any .dll files from other project,
two .dll files.
eg: A.dll,A.pdb
and Rename this two files to your project's name.

Then you can rebuild this project.

Comment: he already included the dll files, but his build failed. your answer does not answer that question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting this without a DLL - just a code file check it's set to compile. In Visual Studio 2013 I keep adding code files and it sets the Build Action (found under Advanced section of Properties of the code file to "Content" rather than "Compile". Change this.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes an explicit naming of the assembly which contains the namespace is required.

```
xmlns:myns="clr-namespace:MyNamespace;assembly=MyAssembly"
```

I don't know why it is sometimes required.