# Project cannot see inside a dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll

Here's what I did so far:

1. Went here and downloaded the source code: http://oggsharp.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#OggSharp/CsVorbis . It came as "oggsharp-19c0361a8fa8.zip" and in there is OggSharp\CsVorbis which has all the .cs files I want.
2. Started a new Class Library project in MS VS 2010. Added all the .cs files from that folder (CsVorbis).
3. Compiled the project. This made a CsVorbisDll.dll file.
4. Went to another project of mine---a MonoGame DirectX project---and added a reference to that dll.
5. Added `using CsVorbisDll;`, and this part works. So it can see the dll. (EDIT: typod it before. It is `using CsVorbisDll;`)
6. Tried to use classes from that dll, such as OggDecoder, **but this doesn't work!** It says "The type or namespace name 'OggDecoder' could not be found"

Apparently my project **can see** the dll, but **cannot see into** the dll. I'm not sure why. The OggDecoder class is public. I noticed, however, that the dll was only 4 KB in size, whereas the source code folder was something like 300 KB. Did it not compile correctly?

I set the Configuration to "Release", not "Debug", when I compiled the dll. My MonoGame Project is also in MS VS 2010, uses DirectX, and otherwise runs fine.

EDIT: What I've verified so far: Both projects target ".NET Framework 4" (not the Client Profile). Both projects have platform target "x86".

Can someone help me set up this dll correctly? I really want it to be a dll. There are too many *.cs from the source to just add them all into my MonoGame Project.

EDIT: I found the answer and posted it. Basically, I had to make the project name the same as the namespace of all the .cs files so that the dll filename is the same as the namespace too.

Comment: Both projects compiled under the same version of .NET?

Comment: *"Added "using CsVorbisDll.dll;", and this part works."*. You should read about the difference between assembly references and using directives.

Comment: @Jonesy yes, both have "Target framework: .NET Framework 4" set in project properties.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski sorry i typod it before. It's "using CsVorbisDll;" with no .dll at the end. I shoulda chose a better name for the dll file tho.

Comment: Did you check that projects are on different 32 bit build mode?

Comment: @faridbekran I just checked, the dll was set to "Any CPU", but my MonoGame Project was set to "x86". They are not both set to "x86". I recompiled and re-tested, but still get the same problem. It can't see inside the dll. If it matters, my machine is 64-bit Windows 7.

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23910959/1095390) steps. maybe it worked. specially cleaning solution. deleting bin/obj folders

Comment: @faridbekran I tried some of those, no luck. Right now I'm hunting through the properties tabs, looking for anything that stands out. Could "Start Actions -> Start External Program" have something to do with it?

Comment: @DrZ214 I don't think so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong, but still don't like it.

The .cs files I was compiling all have `namespace Oggsharp`. So on a whim, I made a new Class Library project and named it OggSharp (instead of CsVorbisDll as before). This time it compiled into an 84 KB dll. I referenced it and was able to use all its classes and functions!

My initial suspicion was right, because CsVorbisDll.dll was compiled as a pitifully small 4 KB dll file. So I guess it didn't compile things into it because the namespaces didnt match up with the dll name?

Upon calling the project OggSharp and making OggSharp.dll, it compiled into an 84 KB dll, with all its insides usable.

Not sure I like this convention/rule. I may do some experiments, e.g., manually renaming the dll and seeing what happens.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dig deep inside dlls you can try [.Net Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/)

You can install the free trial it is good for about 60 days. It installs a new menu into visual studio.

Comment: Or use ilspy, which is free and open source

Comment: I'm baffled when people still recommend Reflector in 2015, especially after the controversy... Just use dotPeek, which is much better (and free), or ReSharper which integrates the decompiler.

Comment: I am looking at purchasing ReSharper. Have you personally used it? Is it worth it?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you also changed all the namespaces, you're using statement is incorrect. It should be:

```
using OggSharp;
```

Comment: I didnt change anything in the source code of OggSharp or CsVorbis. The namespaces it uses are indeed "OggSharp". However, "using OggSharp;" in my MonoGame Project gives an error. It can't see it. But it can see CsVorbisDll. I don't understand it either.